# (In)complete list of Free Chinese Input Methods in current use

Tags: input-methods

I have found this list of **Chinese** (and a few other) **input methods** below, from https://github.com/chinese-opendesktop/cin-tables , from which I am trying to make an updated list.

I can see clearly many familiar Chinese input methods, such as Wubi, Zhengma, Pinyin and Zhuyin.

However, I can also see some character encodings (e.g. BIG-5), and some of the below are probably antiquated.

Can anyone confirm whether these are all ***actually used*** as input methods? (For example, is Big-5 actually used by anyone as an input method, rather than just as an encoding?)

Out of the below, which, for *practical purposes*, are **obsolete**?

Thanks,

L

**中文(繁體),Chinese(Traditional)**

- `3corner.cin,"3Corner(三角編號)","胡立人﹑張源渭﹑黃克東發明的三角編號輸入法;Three Corner Code"`
- `4corner.cin,"4Corner(四角號碼)","王雲五發明的四角號碼輸入法;Four Corner"`
- `4corner5.cin,"4Corner5(四角五碼)","包含第五碼的四角號碼輸入法;Four Corner with fifth code"`
- `array10.cin,"Array10(行列十)","廖明德發明的行列輸入法數字鍵版;Array with 10 keys"`
- `array30.cin,"Array30(行列三十)","廖明德發明的行列輸入法三十鍵版;Array with 30 keys"`
- `array40.cin,"Array40(行列四十)","廖明德發明的行列輸入法四十鍵版;Array with 40 keys"`
- `big5e.cin,"Big5e(五大碼擴充)","包含擴充部分的五大碼;Big5e Code"`
- `big5p.cin,"Big5p(五大碼加強)","包含加強部分的五大碼;Big5p Code"`
- `bopomofo.cin,"Bopomofo(正體注音)","依據全字庫文字屬性規範的注音輸入法;Official Bopomofo"`
- `cangjie.cin,"Cangjie(正體倉頡)","依據全字庫文字屬性規範的倉頡輸入法;Official Cang Jie"`
- `cccii.cin,"CCCII(資訊交換碼)","依據中國文字資料庫的中文資訊交換碼;CCDB CCCII Code"`
- `cns11643.cin,"CNS11643(標準交換碼)","依據 CNS11643 的標準交換碼;CNS 11643 Code"`
- `cnsphoneticlite.cin,"CNSPhoneticLite(全字庫注音精簡)","全字庫注音輸入法精簡版;CNS Phonetic Lite"`
- `dapu.cin,"DaPu(大埔客語)","依據徐登志教材的大埔客語輸入法;Hakka Da-Pu"`
- `dayi3.cin,"DaYi3(大易三碼)","王贊傑發明的大易輸入法三碼版;Da Yi with 3 codes"`
- `dayi4.cin,"DaYi4(大易四碼)","王贊傑發明的大易輸入法四碼版;Da Yi with 4 codes"`
- `dna.cin,"DNA(筆結基因)","程至淵發明的單手十鍵筆結基因輸入法;Knots DNA"`
- `ez.cin,"EZTiny(輕鬆)","高衡緒發明的輕鬆輸入法;Easy tiny"`
- `freenewcj.cin,"FreeNewCJ(自由大新)","相容於蘇清德發明大家的新倉頡輸入法;Free New Cang Jie"`
- `frequency.cin,"Frequency(字頻序)","依據黃世昆所做的字頻統計順序;Character Frequency"`
- `hailu.cin,"HaiLu(海陸客語)","依據現代客語詞彙彙編的海陸客語輸入法;Hakka Hai-Lu"`
- `kks_hakka_henry.cin,"KKS-Hakka(客語漢羅)","客語羅馬字漢羅詞庫輸入法;Hakka KKS"`
- `kks_hakka_tl.cin,"KKS-TLHakka(客語台羅)","客語羅馬字台羅詞庫輸入法;Hakka KKS Tai-Lo"`
- `kks_tl.cin,"KKS-TaiLo(台羅拼音)","台羅拼音漢羅詞庫輸入法;Min-Nan KKS TaiLo"`
- `kks.cin,"KKS(台語漢羅)","台語羅馬字漢羅詞庫輸入法;Min-Nan KKS"`
- `newcj3.cin,"NewCJ3(亂倉打鳥)","張崇巖整理綜合的倉頡輸入法;New Cang Jie 3"`
- `phofsi.cin,"Phofsi(普實台文)","依據台灣語文研究社的最新漢字台文輸入法;Min-Nan Phof Si"`
- `pinyin.cin,"PinYin(正體拼音)","依據全字庫文字屬性規範的漢語拼音輸入法;Official Pin Yin"`
- `poj-holo.cin,"POJ(白話字漢羅)","依據甘為霖的廈門音新字典;Min-Nan POJ"`
- `roman.cin,"Roman(羅馬拼音)","依據全字庫文字屬性規範的羅馬拼音輸入法;Official Roman"`
- `scj6.cin,"SCJ6(快速倉頡)","麥志洪整理綜合的倉頡輸入法;Speed Cang Jie 6"`
- `simplecj.cin,"SimpleCJ(正體簡易)","依據全字庫文字屬性規範的簡易倉頡輸入法;Official Simple Cang Jie"`
- `sixian.cin,"SiXian(四縣客語)","依據臺大客家研究社張凱揮的臺灣客語四縣腔;Hakka Si-Xian"`
- `strokes.cin,"Strokes(筆畫數)","依據中國文字資料庫的全字筆畫數與除去部首筆畫數;CCDB Strokes"`
- `telecode.cin,"Telecode(電信碼)","依據中國文字資料庫的電信碼;CCDB Telecode"`
- `tin.cin,"Taiwanese(臺語注音)","劉宸沂依照吳守禮資料所編的臺語注音輸入法;Min-Nan Bopomofo"`
- `tlim2.cin,"TLIM2(臺灣閩漢)","教育部國語推行委員會的臺灣閩南語漢字輸入法;MOE TLIM2"`
- `tlpa.cin,"TLPA(TLPA台語)","依據台灣閩南語音標系統的輸入法;Min-Nan TLPA"`
- `uanniu.cin,"UanNiu(灣娘臺漢)","採用教育部臺灣閩南語羅馬字拼音方案;Uan Niu Ban Lam"`
- `uniliu.cin,"UniLiu(萬國蝦米)","相容於劉重次發明的嘸蝦米輸入法;Unicode Boshiamy"`
- `whale.cin,"Whale(鯨魚)","台灣之子 MyCJ 發明的鯨魚輸入法;MyCJ Whale"`
- `wm2.cin,"WM2(象形王碼)","王堯世發明的象形王碼輸入法第二代;Wang Ma 2"`
- `boshiamy.cin,"Boshiamy(嘸蝦米)","劉重次發明的嘸蝦米輸入法"`
- `hs.cin,"HS(華象)","陳華偉發明的華象直覺輸入法"`
- `mscj3.cin,"MSCJ3(微軟倉頡)","相容微軟系統內建的倉頡第三代輸入法"`
- `tp_hakka_hl.cin,"TPHL(通用海陸)","陳念波根據徐兆泉所編台灣客家話辭典製作通用拼音客語海陸腔"`
- `tp_hakka_sy.cin,"TPSY(通用四縣)","陳念波根據徐兆泉所編台灣客家話辭典製作通用拼音客語四縣腔"`
- `dayi2.cin,"DaYi2(大易二碼)","王贊傑發明的大易輸入法二碼版;Da Yi with 2 codes"`

**中文(简体),Chinese(Simplified)**

- `pinyin0.cin,"PinYin0(无调拼音)","去除声调的拼音词库输入法;Pin Yin without tone"`
- `erbi-kuai.cin,"ErBi-Kuai(二笔快版)","中文阴阳二笔词库新快版;Er Bi quick"`
- `jtcj.cin,"JTCJ(仓颉)","朱邦复发明的仓颉输入法;Cang Jie for Simplified Chinese"`
- `shuangpin++.cin,"ShuangPin++(双拼加加)","双拼加加词库输入法;Shuang Pin ++"`
- `wbx.cin,"WBX(五笔)","孙海峰整理王永民发明的五笔字形输入法;Hai-Feng Wu Bi"`
- `fcitx-erbi.cin,"ErBi(二笔)","二笔词库输入法;Er Bi"`
- `fcitx-qxm.cin,"QXM(冰蟾全息)","冰蟾全息词库输入法;Quan Xi"`
- `fcitx-wanfeng.cin,"WanFeng(晚风)","晚风词库输入法;Wan Feng"`
- `jinjin.cin,"JinJin(晶晶码)","晶晶系列汉字输入法字母版;Jin Jin Code"`
- `jsm.cin,"JSM(晶数码)","晶晶系列汉字输入法数字版;Jin Shu Code"`
- `soutzoe.cin,"SouTzoe(苏州吴语)","蘇州吳語輸入方案;Sou Tzoe"`
- `wu.cin,"Wu(吴语拼音)","吴语拼音输入法;Wu Pin Yin"`
- `zhengma.cin,"ZhengMa(郑码)","郑易里发明的中易郑码输入法;China-E Zheng Ma"`
- `biaoxing.cin,"BiaoXing(表形码)","陈爱文发明的表形码输入法"`
- `daomax.cin,"DaoMaX(导码)","龚永明发明的全拼形导码输入法"`
- `t9.cin,"T9(Ｔ９笔画)","美国特捷通讯研制的智能输入法"`
- `ziranma.cin,"ZiranMa(自然码)","北京大自然软件开发有限责任公司维护的输入法"`
- `wlkm.cin,"WLKM(王林快码)","湖南人王林发明的一种音形结合的中文输入法"`

**中文(香港),Chinese(Hongkong)**

- `ckc.cin,"CKC(縱橫碼)","周忠繼發明的縱橫碼輸入法;C K Code"`
- `cj5.cin,"Changjei5(倉頡五代)","朱邦復發明的倉頡輸入法第五代;Cang Jie 5"`
- `simplex5.cin,"Simplex5(簡易五代)","朱邦復發明的簡易倉頡輸入法第五代;Simple Cang Jie 5"`
- `simplex.cin,"Simplex(速成)","朱邦復發明的簡易倉頡輸入法;Simple Cang Jie"`
- `jyutping0.cin,"Jyutping0(無調粵拼)","不含音調的粵語拼音;Cantonese Jyutping without tone"`
- `jyutping.cin,"Jyutping(帶調粵拼)","依據香港語言學學會粵語拼音方案的帶調粵語拼音;Cantonese Jyutping"`
- `ile.cin,"ILE(廣東拼音)","依據何國祥的廣東拼音輸入法;Cantonese Jyutping ILE"`
- `cantonhk.cin,"CantonHK(港式廣東話)","香港長者資訊天地製作的拼音輸入法;Cantonese HongKong"`
- `stroke5.cin,"Stroke5(筆順五碼)","香港長者資訊天地製作的筆順輸入法;Stroke 5"`
- `emhz.cin,"EMHZ(Ｅ碼)","王堯世發明的Ｅ碼漢字輸入法"`
- `qcode.cin,"QCode(快碼)","九方科技梁立人﹑劉文建發明的快碼輸入法"`
- `bsm.cin,"BSM(筆順碼)","王頌平發明的筆順碼輸入法"`
- `g6code.cin,"G6Code(六碼筆畫)","布禮文團隊開發的六碼筆畫輸入法"`
- `zyujam.cin,"ZyuJam(粵語注音)","陳錦添版本的粵語注音方案"`

**亞洲(日韓越泰),Asia(JKVT)**

- `halfwidth-kana.cin,"HalfKana(半カタカナ)","日文片假名半形字輸入法;Japanese Halfwidth Katakana"`
- `katakana.cin,"Katakana(カタカナ)","日文片假名全形字輸入法;Japanese Katakana"`
- `hiragana.cin,"Hiragana(ひらがな)","日文平假名全形字輸入法;Japanese Hiragana"`
- `nippon.cin,"Nippon(かんじ)","日文漢字輸入法;Japanese Nippon"`
- `hangul.cin,"Hangul(한글)","韓語諺文輸入法;Korean Hangul"`
- `hangulromaja.cin,"HangulRomaja(한글 Romaja)","韓文羅馬字輸入法;Korean Hangul Romaja"`
- `hanja.cin,"Hanja(한자)","韓文漢字輸入法;Korean Hanja"`
- `viqr.cin,"ViQR(Tiếng Việt QR)","越南文QR排列輸入法;Vietnamese QR"`
- `vims.cin,"ViMS(Tiếng Việt MS)","越南文MS排列輸入法;Vietnamese MS"`
- `vitelex.cin,"ViTelex(Tiếng Việt Telex)","越南文Telex排列輸入法;Vietnamese Telex"`
- `vivni.cin,"ViVNI(Tiếng Việt VNI)","越南文VNI排列輸入法;Vietnamese VNI"`
- `thai.cin,"Thai(ภาษาไทย)","泰文輸入法;Thai Kesmanee from m17n-db"`

Comment: My favorite and perhaps the most common of course is handwriting recognition :-) And my second is via translation from English. Years ago when everyone was using DOS, HK Cantonese speakers were not taught Pinyin in school nor were Cantonese phonetics widely known so some characters we had to find in radical charts - a third input method not on any list here. Funny thing about the radical charts, they counted strokes according to simplified Chinese so some characters like 瑩 / 莹 were not even under the expected radical because simplification changed that! In some ways simplifying isn't simple:-)

Comment: For Linux (but also for Windows etc.), the only handwriting recognition I have found is mozc. It was made for Japanese by Google, but you can also install models for Chinese handwriting recognition. On ubuntu 20.04: `sudo apt-get install ibus-mozc mozc-utils-gui` and also `sudo apt-get install tegaki-zinnia-traditional-chinese` or `sudo apt-get install tegaki-zinnia-traditional-chinese`. Then run from terminal with `/usr/lib/mozc/mozc_tool --mode=hand_writing`. Source: https://jameswaugh.com/code/handwriting-recognition-in-mozc/

Comment: There is also Pablo, https://pablopingrid.blogspot.com , which is for Windows, but also on Linux using Wine, and possibly also Mac.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have added some details to the input methods above.

- Grouped by country of origin
- Removed the character codes (i.e. Big5,Telecode, CNS11643, CCCII).
- Character sets (trad./simp.) and number of characters is *taken from the tables at Chinese-OpenDesktop above (see link)*, and so could be larger if updated elsewhere.
- Actively developed or not. Related to this is the last version of Windows the method with a release, and if the weblink is now only available on Internet archive.

The country of origin is derived from the homepage address (e.g. .tw or .cn). A few appear uncertain, e.g. wm2 has a traditional character set, but appears to have a mainland address...

I hope this is useful for picking an input method. The OpenDesktop list is probably Linux-favouring, so there may be many others, as well as their variations.There are probably errors - please point them out.

### **People's Republic of China**

| Code (English Name) | Name | Origin | No. of chars | First release | Last Active | Windows | Char set | Method | Input | Obsolete | Notes and Links |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 corner | 四角號碼 | CN | 35262 | 1925 |  |  | BOTH | GRAPHICAL/ SPLIT CHAR | Numeric |  | https://dbpedia.org/page/Four-Corner_Method |
| biaoxing | 表形码输入法 | CN | 21608 | 1986 | 2018 | Win 95/98 (pre-installed), Win 7,8,10 | BOTH | GRAPHICAL/ SPLIT CHAR | alphabet. |  | http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/表形码 http://www.ddooo.com/softdown/29752.htm |
| daomax | 全拼形导码 | CN | 15486 | 1999 | updated ?2008 |  | BOTH | GRAPHICAL/ SPLIT CHAR / STROKE | alphabet. |  | https://web.archive.org/web/20080225080821/http://input.foruto.com/gbqpxdm/xxdm.htm https://patents.google.com/patent/CN1062667C/zh |
| emjh / emhz ("E-code") | Ｅ碼漢字 | CN | 26280 | 1990 | 2006 |  | BOTH | GRAPHICAL | alphabet. |  | Chinese-English pictogram: based on English letters with similar shapes, e.g. 匚=C https://web.archive.org/web/268291947/http://www.km2000.com.cn |
| ErBi-Kuai (Er Bi quick) | 二笔快版 | CN | 84719 | 1992 | 2000 |  | BOTH | PHONETIC / STROKE | alphabet. |  | https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%BA%8C%E7%AC%94%E8%BE%93%E5%85%A5%E6%B3%95 https://web.archive.org/web/20080517212814/http://qseb.ys168.com/ |
| ez | 轻松 | ? | 14751 |  | ?2000 |  | TRAD | ? | alphanum. |  | ? |
| flypy | 小鹤音形 | CN | 13703 | 2006 | Active |  | SIMP | PHONETIC | alphabet. |  | https://www.flypy.com/ |
| jtcj (Chan Jei/ Cang Jie for Simp. CN) | 倉頡 | MY | 6725 |  | ?1997 |  | SIMP | ? | alphabet. |  | Cangjie based https://web.archive.org/web/20010502233142/http://www.geocities.com/rainforest/9178/maincjgb.htm |
| Pinyin | 正体拼音 | CN | 85244 |  | ? |  | BOTH | PHONETIC | alphabet. |  | ? |

**PRC (cont.)**

| Code (English Name) | Name |  | No. of chars | First release | Active | Windows | Char set | Method | Input | Obsolete | Notes / Links |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| QXM (Quan Xi/ Bingchan) | 冰蟾全息 | CN | 21655 |  | 1990 |  | SIMP | PHONETIC (& RADICAL BASED) | alphabet. |  | Considered a breakthrough at first, then went to a court case https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-hans/%E6%B1%89%E5%AD%97%E5%85%A8%E6%81%AF%E7%A0%81 [https://www.xzbu.com/2/view-6106469.htm|](https://www.xzbu.com/2/view-6106469.htm%7C) |
| ShuangPin++ | 双拼加加 | CN | 20967 |  | ? |  | SIMP | PHONETIC | alphabet. |  | https://github.com/macroxue/shuangpin |
| T9 | - | CN? | 12235 |  | Active |  | SIMP | STROKE | 5 keys (psnhz) |  | T9 输入法一直是手机输入法的标配 (mobile phone input) [https://github.com/microcai/ibus-t9|](https://github.com/microcai/ibus-t9%7C) |
| wanfeng | 晚风 | CN | 89640 |  | ? |  | SIMP | ? |  |  |  |
| wbx (Hai-Feng Wu Bi) | 海峰五笔 | CN | 25168 |  | Active |  | BOTH | Split char | alphabet. |  | Wubi 86 was Simple only. Version at opendesktop above is Wubi 98 https://www.xyttt.com/f/9j2GbKEZym.htmlhttps://web.archive.org/web/20110227075427/http://okuc.net/sunwb/ |
| WLKM | 王林快码 | ? | 28530 |  | ? |  | BOTH | MIXED | alphabet. |  |  |
| wm2 (Wang Ma 2) | 象形王碼 | CN | 13053 |  | ? |  | TRAD | Split char? | alphabet. |  | Pictographic code, 2nd gen |
| zhengma | 中易鄭碼 | CN | 89176 |  |  |  | BOTH | STROKES | alphabet. |  | www.zmfans.cn/bbs https://github.com/acevery/ibus-table-zhengma |
| ZiRanMa ('Natural' code) | 自然码 | CN | 58557 |  | 2009 | Win 8 | SIMP | PHONETIC / CODE | alphabet. |  | https://web.archive.org/web/20150219103838/ [http://www.zrm.com.cn/|](http://www.zrm.com.cn/%7C) |

### **PRC (Other dialects)**

All the below are phonetic input.

| Code (English Name) | Name | Dialect | No. of chars) | First release | Active | Windows | Char set | Method | Notes and Links |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Soutzoe | 蘇州吳語 | SUZHOU | 5363 |  | 2013 |  | TRAD | alphabet. |  |
| wu (Wu Pin Yin) | 吴语拼音 | WU (SHANGHAI) | 18525 (chars and phrases) |  |  |  | BOTH | alphabet. |  |

### **Hong Kong SAR**

| Code (English Name) | Name | No. of chars | Active | Windows | Char set | Method | Input | Notes andLinks |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| bsm | 筆順碼輸入法 | 53924 | 2000 (unofficial update 2018) |  | TRAD | STROKE | Numeric |  |
| cangjie (Official Cang Jie) | 網上倉頡輸入法 | 70499 | First release 1976 |  | BOTH | GRAPHICAL /SPLIT CHAR | alphabet. |  |
| cantonhk (Cantonese Pinyin) | 港式廣東話 | 14015 | 2003 |  | TRAD | PHONETIC | alphabet. |  |
| CKC (C K Code) | 縱橫碼 | 23976 | Active |  | BOTH | GRAPHICAL/ SPLIT CHAR | Numeric |  |
| G6Code | 六碼筆畫 | 13156 | 2017 |  | TRAD | STROKE | Numeric |  |
| ILE (Cantonese Jyutping ILE) | 廣東拼音 | 17445 | ? |  | BOTH | PHONETIC | alphanum. |  |
| Jinjin | 晶晶碼 | 17957 (+10582 phrases) | ? |  | TRAD | ? | alphabet. |  |
| JSM (Jin Shu) | 晶数码 | 33703 | 2006 | 98/Me/XP | BOTH | ?PHONETIC /GRAPHICAL | Numeric |  |

**Hong Kong (cont.)**

| Code (English Name) | Name | No. of chars | Active | Windows | Char set | Method | Input | Notes and Links |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| jyupting (Cantonese Jyutping) | 帶調粵語拼音 | 17446 | 1993 |  | BOTH | PHONETIC | alphanum. |  |
| mscj3 (changjei3) | 微倉三 | 22183 | ? |  | BOTH | ? | alphabet. |  |
| NewCJ3 (New Cang Jie 3) | 亂倉打鳥 | 140526 chars and phrases | ? | 98 | TRAD | ? | alphabet. |  |
| q9 | 九方字形 | ? | Active |  | TRAD? | GRAPHICAL/ SPLIT CHAR | Numeric |  |
| SCJ (Speedy Cangjie) | 快速倉頡 | 77297 | 2009 | Win 7 | TRAD | GRAPHICAL/ SPLIT CHAR | alphabet. |  |
| Simplex (Simple Cang Jie) | 速成 | 13056 | ? |  | TRAD | ? | alphabet. |  |
| Simplex5 | 簡五 | 32698 | ? |  | BOTH | ? | alphabet. |  |
| whale (MyCJ Whale) | 鯨魚 | 31410 | 2000 |  | BOTH | Split char? | alphabet. |  |
| ZyuJam | 粵語注音 | 17446 | ? |  | BOTH | PHONETIC | alphanum. |  |

### **Republic of China (Taiwan)**

| Code (English Name) | Name | No. of chars | Active | Char set | Method | Input | Notes and Links |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Triangle / 3 corner | 三角編號 | 32889 |  | TRAD | GRAPHICAL/ SPLIT CHAR | Numeric |  |
| array40 | 行列40 | 14737 | - | TRAD | GRAPHICAL/ SPLIT CHAR | alphabet. | OBS |
| array30 | 行列30 | 88157 | 2007 | BOTH | GRAPHICAL/ SPLIT CHAR | alphanum. |  |
| array10 | 行列10 | 69,720 - (Unicode 3.1, incl. ext. A&B) | 2018 | BOTH | GRAPHICAL/ SPLIT CHAR | Numeric |  |
| Bopomofo (Zhuyin) (Official Bopomofo) | 正體注音 | 85243 | 2010 | BOTH | PHONETIC | alphanum. |  |  |
| boshiamy | 嘸蝦米 / 無蝦米 | 26341 | Active | TRAD (SIMP add-on availble) | GRAPHICAL/ SPLIT CHAR | alphabet. |  |
| cbs (ChineseEasy) | 中易拼形 | 760 | 2018 | TRAD | STROKE | Numeric |  |
| CNSPhoneticlite | 全字庫注音 | 93198 | 2016 | BOTH | PHONETIC | alphanum. |  |
| dna | 筆結基因 | 17802 | ?2005 | BOTH | ? | Numeric |  |
| dragonfly | 龍飛 | 26217 | 2009 | TRAD | ? | alphanum. |  |

**Taiwan (cont.)**

| Code (English Name) | Name | No. of chars | Active | Char set | Method | Input | Notes and Links |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| FreeNewCJ | 自由大新 | 38098 | Active | BOTH | GRAPHICAL/ SPLIT CHAR | alphabet. |  |
| SimpleCJ (Official Simple Cang Jie) | 正體簡易 | 70490 | ? | BOTH | GRAPHICAL/ SPLIT CHAR | alphabet. |  |
| Strokes (CCDB Strokes) | 筆畫數 | 33291 | ? | TRAD | STROKE | Numeric |  | ? |
| Stroke5 | 筆順五碼 | 26381 | ? | BOTH | STROKE | 5 keys (nm,. /) |  |
| Taiwanese | 臺語注音 | 21075 | 2009 | TRAD | PHONETIC | alphanum. |  |
| Trs (Taiwan Romanisation System) | 臺語TRS | 60667 (chars and phrases) |  | TRAD | PHONETIC | alphanum. |  |
| UniLiu (Unicode Boshiamy) | 萬國蝦米 | 97086 |  | BOTH | GRAPHICAL/ SPLIT CHAR | alphabet. |  |

### **Taiwanese dialects**

All below are phonetic input and use the traditional character-set.

| Code (English Name) | Name | Dialect | No. of chars | Active | Input | Obsolete | Notes and Links |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| HaiLu | 海陸客語 | HAKKA (HaiLu dialect - 海陸客語) | 5060 | 2008 | alphanum. |  | https://www.edu.tw/Default.aspx?wid=c5ad5187-55ef-4811-8219-e946fe04f725 |
| hkim1 (Hakka Pinyin Input Method) | 臺客四縣 | HAKKA | 4925 | ? | alphabet. | OBS? | by Taiwan Ministry of Education [https://www.edu.tw/Default.aspx?wid=c5ad5187-55ef-4811-8219-e946fe04f726|](https://www.edu.tw/Default.aspx?wid=c5ad5187-55ef-4811-8219-e946fe04f726%7C) |
| hkim2 (Hakka Pinyin Input Method) | 臺客海陸 | HAKKA | 5183 | ? | alphabet. | OBS? | ? [https://www.edu.tw/Default.aspx?wid=c5ad5187-55ef-4811-8219-e946fe04f727|](https://www.edu.tw/Default.aspx?wid=c5ad5187-55ef-4811-8219-e946fe04f727%7C) |
| hkim3 (Hakka Pinyin Input Method) | 臺客大埔 | HAKKA | 5254 | ? | alphabet. | OBS? | [https://www.edu.tw/Default.aspx?wid=c5ad5187-55ef-4811-8219-e946fe04f728|](https://www.edu.tw/Default.aspx?wid=c5ad5187-55ef-4811-8219-e946fe04f728%7C) |
| hkim4 (Hakka Pinyin Input Method) | 臺客饒平 | HAKKA | 5481 | ? | alphabet. | OBS? | [https://www.edu.tw/Default.aspx?wid=c5ad5187-55ef-4811-8219-e946fe04f729|](https://www.edu.tw/Default.aspx?wid=c5ad5187-55ef-4811-8219-e946fe04f729%7C) |
| hkim5 (Hakka Pinyin Input Method) | 臺客詔安 | HAKKA | 5033 | ? | alphabet. | OBS? | [https://www.edu.tw/Default.aspx?wid=c5ad5187-55ef-4811-8219-e946fe04f730|](https://www.edu.tw/Default.aspx?wid=c5ad5187-55ef-4811-8219-e946fe04f730%7C) |
| hkim6 (Hakka Pinyin Input Method) | 臺客南四 | HAKKA | 4977 | ? | alphabet. |  | [https://www.edu.tw/Default.aspx?wid=c5ad5187-55ef-4811-8219-e946fe04f731|](https://www.edu.tw/Default.aspx?wid=c5ad5187-55ef-4811-8219-e946fe04f731%7C) |
| KKS (Min-Nan KKS) | 台語漢羅 | ?HAKKA (Han Luo dialect) | 42414 chars and phrases | ? | alphanum. |  |  |
| KKS-Hakka (Hakka KKS) | 客语汉罗 | HaKKA | 36263 chars and phrases | ? | alphanum. |  | ? |
| KKS-TLHakka (Hakka KKS Tai-Lo) | 客語台羅 | HAKKA | 45487 chars and phrases | ? | alphanum. |  | ? |

**Taiwanese dialects (cont.)**

| Code (English Name) | Name | Dialect | No. of chars | Active | Input | Obsolete | Notes and Links |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Phofsi (Min-Nan Phof Si) | 普實台文 | MINNAN | 16084 | ? | alphabet. |  | https://web.archive.org/web/25255549/http://daibuun.tacocity.com.tw/ |
| Poj-holo | 白話字漢羅 | MINNAN | 15864 |  |  |  |  |
| SiXian (Hakka Si-Xian) | 四縣客語 | HAKKA (Sixian dialect) | 6243 | ? |  |  | ? |
| Taiwan MinNan ZhuYin | 台式閩南語注音 | MINNAN | 7338 | ? | alphanum. |  |  |
| Tin (Min-Nan Bopomofo) | 臺語注音 | MINNAN | 20998 |  | alphanum. |  | Zhuyin beta version 臺語注音輸入法 測試版 (Alternative Zhuyin version of Taiwanese Zhuyin above) |
| Tlim2 | 臺灣閩漢 | MINNAN | 52873 (chars and phrases) | 2015 | alphanum. |  |  |
| TLPA (Min-Nan TLPA) | 台語 | MINNAN | 33589 (chars and phrases) |  | alphanum. |  | https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-hant/%E8%87%BA%E7%81%A3%E8%AA%9E%E8%A8%8%E9%9F%B3%E6%A8%99%E6%96%B9%E6%A1%88 |
| tp_hakka_hl (HoiLiuk - Four counties) | 通用海陸 | HAKKA (通用海陸) | 38682 |  | alphabet. |  |  |
| tp_hakka_sy (SiYen - Land and Sea) | 通用四縣 | HAKKA ( 通用四縣) | 38638 |  | alphabet. |  |  |
| UanNiu (Uan Niu Ban Lam) | 灣娘臺漢 | MINNAN | 36301 (chars and phrases) |  | alphanum. |  | Taiwanese Romanized Minnan pinyin input [https://web.archive.org/web/2117191438/http://www.openfoundry.org/of/projects/1928|](https://web.archive.org/web/2117191438/http://www.openfoundry.org/of/projects/1928%7C) |

Comment: One correction - the Republic of China (Taiwan), or the Republic of China - Taiwan are both in use around the world, but there is no such State named the Republic of Taiwan. The governments on both sides of the Taiwan Strait claim Taiwan is a non-separatable part of the China up to now.

Comment: The informal English name of the ROC is just "Taiwan". There is no such political entity called "The Republic of Taiwan".

Comment: Thank you both. I went with the political names, for reasons I'm not sure of.

Comment: Cangjie originated in Taiwan, though it is also extremely popular in Hong Kong.